# Multiple PDFs in Loop with FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have a FDPF function that creates a standard PDF for various parts of the website. It simply takes some data in, creates a multi page PDF and returns the PDF object e.g.

```
function pdfBuild($orderData) {



class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
    // Logo
    $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Title
    //$this->Cell(80,10,'Game Sheet',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}



}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
   for($a=0;$a<count($orderData);$a++) {
    $pdf->AddPage();
    //Add stuff to PDF
   }
return $pdf;

}
```

My issue arises in a loop that emails individual PDFs out to clients e.g

```
function buildPDFs() {

    //Get a location
    $query = "GET SOME CLIENT INFORMATION";
    $result = getSQLConnection($query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                //Get some info from dB using $row

                //Format info from db into $data variable

                $pdf = pdfBuild($data);

                //Test Data
                $to = 'stackoverflow@question.com';
                $from = 'hello@clientinfo.com';
                $subject = 'PDFs'
                $message = 'Howdy';
                //End
                emailPDF($pdf, $to, $from, $subject, $message);

            }
    }

    echo 'Done';

}
```

The problem is that if I do two iterations of the loop, the attachment is the PDF that was generated in the first instance but I get two emails with the same attachment. As such it would appear the $pdf object never changes in the loop, even though I am certain the data being passed to the PDF generation function each time is different. The generated PDFs are identical.

Do I need to unset or otherwise 'destroy' the PDF object each time in the loop?

**Update**

The removal of Class definition of Header and Footer, as in the above code snippet, solves the problem. But I can't understand why.

**Question**: Why does the removal of the 'class extend' code solve the problem and allow the loop to generate different PDFs each time, as expected, and email them correctly?

**Answer below from Veve and solves the problem. I was mis-declaring and completely misusing the Class**

Comment: if the pdf does not change, build it outside the loop just once

Comment: Where do you define `$data` inside of your function?

Comment: @nogad, could you expand on your answer. How do I build it 'once'?

BenM, the data is built using another function. I can confirm its changing on each iteration of the loop and being sent. The PDF object is not changing however.

Comment: move `$pdf = pdfBuild($data);` to before the loop starts, current you recreate the same pdf for every send.

Comment: Thanks @nogad, but I am changing $data on each iteration using the $row from the dB. I've updated my code above to reflect this. It would appear the function pdfBuild is always returning the same $pdf.

Comment: how about more real code. as in how your attaching the pdf.

Comment: Thanks @nogad, I did some testing this morning and have updated my code above. If I comment out the class PDF entirely, including the Header and Footer, the code works as expected. However, I need a Header and Footer in my implementation.

Comment: You're mixing the declaration of a function and a class in it, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Thanks @Veve, I guessed that was my error. Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the removal of the 'class extend' code solve the problem and
>   allow the loop to generate different PDFs each time, as expected, and
>   email them correctly?

It's because you're mixing the declaration of a function and a class in it.

To resolve it, first create <kbd>pdf.php</kbd> with your extended class, which only override the desired methods:

```
require_once('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // Page header
    function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(80);
        // Title
        //$this->Cell(80,10,'Game Sheet',1,0,'C');
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }

    // Page footer
    function Footer()
    {
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}
```

After that, in your <kbd>code.php</kbd> you can then use this class, with the code you use for generating the PDF in its own function:

```
require_once('pdf.php');

function pdfBuild($orderData) {
    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
       for($a=0;$a<count($orderData);$a++) {
        $pdf->AddPage();
        //Add stuff to PDF
       }
    return $pdf;
}

function buildPDFs() {

    //Get a location
    $query = "GET SOME CLIENT INFORMATION";
    $result = getSQLConnection($query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                //Get some info from dB using $row

                //Format info from db into $data variable

                $pdf = pdfBuild($data);

                //Test Data
                $to = 'stackoverflow@question.com';
                $from = 'hello@clientinfo.com';
                $subject = 'PDFs'
                $message = 'Howdy';
                //End
                emailPDF($pdf, $to, $from, $subject, $message);

            }
    }

    echo 'Done';

}
```