# PHP mailer and FPDF attachment with loop - script stops after first run

Tags: loops, phpmailer, fpdf

I'm running a following script to generate and send email. The email body is generated in a while loop (content differs) - it works fine. But now I have tried to include a script to generate PDF attachment (via FPDF library), in each iteration the attachment is different.

Problem is: the loop runs just once, for the first case and after it stops. Thank you for your commnents in advance.

My code:

```
<?
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                                
$mail->isSMTP();   
$mail->addReplyTo('');
$mail->isHTML(true);                              
$mail->Subject = "";
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587;                                    
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->setFrom('');

while(($data=MySQL_Fetch_Array($vysl))!=NULL) {
require_once('invoicetopdf.php');
$message="";
$mail->AddStringAttachment($invoice, 'Invoice.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');
$mail->Username = "";
$mail->Password = "";
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->Body = $message;

if (!$mail->send()) {echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;} 

else {

$mail->clearAddresses();
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->clearAttachments(); 

echo "Ok";

}  
} //while

//invoicetopdf.php:

$data = MySQL_Fetch_Array($vysl);     

require_once('../knihovny/pdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->.....;

$invoice=$pdf->Output('S');

?>
```

Comment: The given code is not complete - it should throw a syntax error on that line with all the dots. Additionally, `MySQL_Fetch_Array` has been removed years ago

Comment: Yes, the dots shortens a great piece of code which is following  (it's not important in this case  :) the invoicetopdf.php generates attachment. correctly, unfortunately just once, not repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of an odd way to run that code repeatedly. I would define a function in your `invoicetopdf.php` file, load it at the top of your script, and then call the function inside the loop to get the PDF data. You're also calling `mysql_fetch_array` twice - once in the while loop, once in the function, meaning half your data will be going astray.

```php
require_once('invoicetopdf.php');
while(($data=MySQL_Fetch_Array($vysl))!=NULL) {
$message="";
$mail->AddStringAttachment(generatePDF($data), 'Invoice.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');
...
```

```php
//invoicetopdf.php:
require_once('../knihovny/pdf/fpdf.php');
function generatePDF($data) {
    $pdf = new PDF();
    $pdf->.....;
    return $invoice=$pdf->Output('S');
}
```

I also recommend moving the `Username` and `Password` out of the loop, and you probably don't need to call `clearAllRecipients()`; `clearAddresses()` is enough.

Setting `SMTPDebug = 2` will let you see more of what's happening in SMTP land.

Comment: Thank you for help. I will try that. It's a part of a greater project, so the script is a litle bit complicated :)  Some things have reasons (eq, user and pass are in loop because emails are not always sent from the same Gmail account :)

Answer (score 0):

Now it works: the main problem was a mixing a class and functions together. See:[Multiple PDFs in Loop with FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094584/multiple-pdfs-in-loop-with-fpdf?rq=1)

Thank you guys!